# Is it true that $T^2\# T^2\simeq T^2\# \overline{T^2}$? What about $M\# N$ and $M\# \overline{N}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology

Is it true that connected sum of two copy of a torus  homeomorphic to connected sum of a torus and another torus with opposite orientation? i.e.
$$T^2\#  T^2\simeq T^2\# \overline{T^2}?$$

If the answer is positive, I am interested in both geometrical (using a square with identified edges) and algebraic proof.

I think the proof is as follows: By the classification of closed surfaces it is known that $T^2\# \overline{T^2}$ is homeomorphic to connected sum of a torus and a $\Bbb RP^2$ or another torus. But I think $T^2\# \overline{T^2}$ is orientable so it should be $T^2\# T^2$. Is this proof correct? Is there another approach?

What can be say in general ($n\geq 3$) for $M\# N$ and  $M\# \overline{N}$?

Comment: Just curious, by "opposite orientation", do you mean reversed orientation of the attaching map? If so, then my intuition tells me that it depends on specific cases. And the orientability somehow affects the conclusion? (Just a guess)

Comment: I think $\Bbb{CP}^n$ demonstrates the idea, it does not necessarily have a reversed orientation self-homeomorphism unless specific conditions are satisfied.

Comment: @C.F.G Honestly, I wrote the comment to quickly and I'm not sure if it really conveyed the right information. The thing about the torus reversing orientation implying they are diffeomorphic is correct. As for bordism, there is several places to look. Milnor and Stashev say a couple things about them in relation to characteristic classes. Where I learned the algebraic parts about bordism was Haynes Miller's "Complex Cobordism". There is also a geometric aspect which is related to Morse Theory and handle decompositions. You could look at Milnor's book on Morse Theory.

Comment: It is certainly a very beautiful and important theory that can be studied in many different ways. Under the lens of bordism though, it is correct to say that this is like comparing $x+y$ and $x-y$.

Comment: Just notice that the torus has an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism (If you want to use a square, then it is a reflection. It's easier to consider the self-map of $S^1\times S^1$ which interchanges the factors). To see how things fall apart in higher dimensions it's instructive to consider simply connected 4-manifolds. For instance $\mathbb{C}P^2\#\overline{\mathbb{C}P}^2\cong\overline{\mathbb{C}P}^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2$ admits an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism, whilst $\mathbb{C}P^2\#\mathbb{C}P^2$ does not.

Comment: @Tyrone: As far as I can conclude from "admitting  an orientation-reversing diffeomorphism" is that Diff group of one has an element that is not in other one. so they are not diffeo. Right? Or can be say more?

Comment: Right (diffeomorphic manifolds have isomorphic diffeomorphism groups). What more can be said depends on what you ask. For instance $T^2$ having an orienation-reversing diffeomorphism immedaitely gives $M\#T^2\cong M\#\overline T^2$ for any orientable surface $M$, so it's certinaly a useful feature to acknowledge.